# XAML Designer Crash in VS 2015 on Win 10

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

I created a brand new application, opened the XAML editor on the form that VS creates by default, and it crashes. I asked my original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778891/windows-10-vs-2015-xaml-designer-crash). Someone mistakenly marked it as a duplicate. Clearly my question isn't about null reference exceptions!

I tried debugging this with another instance of VS. However, I was never able to see when the exception was thrown.

Comment: That sounds quite annoying. Is it only when you open the XAML editor? (What happens with a new Console, or WinForms application?)

I'm still using VS2013 on Win8.1 and sometimes the XAML editor freezes for extended periods of time. I 'solve' it by killing all "XDesProc" designer processes (one for each XAML designer) and clicking reload. But unsure if this will help you.

Comment: do you have any VS extensions?

Comment: There is a long list of complaints about the same problem over at social.msdn [VS 2015 Designer error (Designer will not load)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb8c2193-8ef7-4bda-b695-84ab638efaef/vs-2015-designer-error-designer-will-not-load?forum=vssetup)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, worked for me on an HP laptop:

delete the "Platform" environment variable in System->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables ...

In my case it said =HPD

Comment: Wow! That seems to have worked for me also. I had a different platform value, but I just deleted it. I wonder what unintended consequences will result from this, though.

Comment: I found a whole discussion about this, it seems as this variable is set by HP during OS setup and not really needed for anything by them, but VS interprets it in a different way. Glad it worked for you too. In my case it was 1 HP laptop and 1 HP PC which had this problem and on none of the other systems (VM or none HP).

Comment: HP have a habit of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100238/the-outputpath-property-is-not-set-for-this-project-error/9944743#9944743