# Visual Studio 2015 XAML designer fails with System.Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Community on Windows 10 Pro official release. Visual Studio installed without any problems or errors, but the XAML designer is crashing with the following error:

[image]

```
System.Exception
Install failed. Please contact your software vendor.

Deployment Register operation with target volume C: on Package 74da95b4-525a-49a9-99a1-472cc815a148_1.0.0.0_x86_NorthAmerica_8wekyb3d8bbwe from:  (AppXManifest.xml)  failed with error 0x8E5E0408. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app, but the problem has nothing to do with my app, because I tried to create a blank Windows 10 UWP app and a blank Windows 8.1 Universal app, both with the same error when trying to open the XAML designer for the default MainPage.xaml.

I also tried debugging Visual Studio with another instance of it, but it didn't throw any exception.

This seems to be a bug in the XAML designer, but if anyone knows a working workaround, please share it with me.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

The problem was solved by the Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

Comment: Are you running a legal copy?

Comment: Yes, I had Windows 8.1 Pro (legal) and upgraded to 10 Pro for free. It says that my Windows is activated. And VS2015 is free from Microsoft website, so it's legal too.

Comment: I have the same problem, has the problem been solved yet?

Answer (score 1):

You need turn on the Developer Mode. Go to Settings app --> `Update and Security` --> `For Developers` menu. Please refer to below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I have done that and rebooted and made sure that the developer mode is enabled, but I still have the problem. Thanks for help!

Comment: I am sure it is to do with Developer Mode. My system was working fine for weeks and then after a big update it stopped. I went to "For Developers", it was still set to Developer Mode from before but as soon as the window opened it started "installing". Then the designer worked again.

Comment: Due to some reason, I was unable to select `Developer mode` radio button from settings app. The radio button was enabled but clicking on it had no effect. Then, I had go via Group Policy route to enable this option as mentioned in [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/manage-developer-mode-on-windows-10-using-group-policy/ba-p/400312#:~:text=In%20Group%20Policy%20Editor%20navigate,and%20click%20on%20Enabled%20button.) link.

Answer (score 1):

For many others, deleting the "Platform" environment variable in System->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables has solved the problem (mainly on HP PC's or laptops).

You might want to give it a shot. For more info, see [XAML designer crash in VS 2015 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786534/xaml-designer-crash-in-vs-2015-on-win-10/31820280#31820280)

Comment: This is only for HP computers, didn't solve the problem on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the xaml. Choose open with XML (Text) editor. (set as default). The automatic editor selector not always works.

Answer (score 0):

I **disabled** the Developer Mode (Setting-> Update & Security -> For developers -> Don't use developer features) and  reboot computer. It solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, but after reboot the designer still failed. I also tried to re-enable the Developer Mode, but it didn't help either.

Comment: After all I solved the problem. In my MVVM light application initialization a database context was in constructor of ViewModelLocator. Each time, when window of XAML designer opened,there was creation a connection to database. It spent a lot of time. When I removed create a connection to database from the constructor of ViewModelLocator, XAML the editor began to open quickly.
You can test your application for long-running operations which can be execution when you open XAML editor

Comment: I'd like to try that, but I don't understand what you mean with "a database context was in constructor of ViewModelLocator". And my problem is not that the designer takes long to load, but it doesn't load at all. That also happens with a new, blank app.