# XAML crashing continuously Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm running VS2015 on a Win10 machine. I cannot work without having xaml designer crash. I've tried disabling running project code, restarting, etc. Nothing is working. I've searched the web and I am finding absolutely nothing.

```
Microsoft.MetadataReader.UnresolvedAssemblyException
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
```

What are my options?

EDIT: The HP env var fix doesn't work

Comment: You will need to include Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure into your project, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786534/xaml-designer-crash-in-vs-2015-on-win-10) help?

To quote the user [Roman Mueller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695008/roman-mueller) :

> Try this, worked for me on an HP laptop:
>
> delete the "Platform" environment variable in System->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables ...
>
> In my case it said =HPD

Comment: Not using HP machine unfortunately.

Comment: I assume your VS15 is up to date? Do you by any chance have Blend installed?

Comment: I do have blend and it crashes there as well. Currently repairing my installation.